# How is firebase able to detect "app_remove"

Tags: java, android, firebase

In firebase analytics for Android apps, I can see app_remove events. But Android OS, does not provide any callback to detect if the app is getting uninstalled.

So does firebase actually get to know if "app_remove" event took place?

Comment: what you want to do actually??

Comment: I guess it's using the [ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED) broadcast message for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the firebase docs,the app_remove event occurs "when an application package is removed or "uninstalled" from an Android device."

For more details visit : 
https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485?hl=en

Comment: does that mean that when I have firebase linked and I remove and install new versions of the application during the development these events will be counted?

Comment: This is a late comment but yes during development this even fires each time a new apk is copied to your device.

Comment: Can we also get the user information when an app is uninstalled?

Comment: @ShajeelAfzal Did you find any information about  your question?

Comment: yes, you can get user information when app is uninstalled @ShajeelAfzal