# Firebase: I need to clean up database once a user uninstalls the app IOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am making an app for Android and iOS and I have authentication for my users. My users must update the database once they log in or log out from the app.

**Problem:**

An user might uninstall the app before he/she log out of the app, thus the user won't be able to make the update.

**Possible Solution:**

I think that Firebase will allow me to trigger a function on the `app_remove` event from Firebase analytics. But I don't know if it is precise. For example, if the user uninstalls while offline he/she won't trigger the function.

**Question:**

Any clean solution that will help me do a database update for users after they uninstall my app?

Comment: I think there is no reliable way to do this. You always can check last login date and if this is greater than "x" you can assume the user uninstalled the app.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45744408/cloud-functions-for-firebase-can-you-detect-app-uninstall, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41845013/how-is-firebase-able-to-detect-app-remove. Beyond that you seem to ask a reference to code that cleans up your database when this happens, which is off topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I read the links before, but I don't know if app_remove is reliable. Example how analytics will know a user uninstalled the app while offline?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen also is app_remove available for ios or just android?

Comment: As Jen says in answer to the linked question: `app_remove` is only available on Android. If you are having problems with it not firing, show the minimal code/steps to reproduce that problem.